# sending DDP ping with data from meteor server

Tags: c++, meteor, ping

Is there a way to send a DDP ping with string data from the server to a connected client?  I am looking for a way to send asynchronous data from the server to the client over the DDP link.  The data might not necessarily be associated with a mongo collection as the client may be a c++ client.

Thanks

Comment: Which C++ client are you using for DDP?

Comment: This is the [out-of-the-box use of Meteor methods](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/ddp/DDP.md#remote-procedure-calls). Why not use them?

Comment: I built a quick and dirty c++ client using easywsclient: https://github.com/dhbaird/easywsclient and a little bit of code on top of that, mainly to send and handle the connect, ping and RPC DDP messages.  The goal is to interface to cloud services using the server side of Meteor where it would expose a set of methods invoked via RPC from various clients.  In particular, an embedded system is where the c++ client lives.  The browser side of the Meteor app acts as both a test bed and control over the server side.

Comment: There were two reasons I wanted to examine ping as a message transport.  It furnished a simple way to asynchronously send events to the c++ client without having to deal with the pub/sub aspect since in this simple case, it is not a db based app.  I wanted to keep it simple.  I am also having problem sending the params [] array of args to a target method.  I can invoke a meteor server side method from c++ methods without args but the server disconnects when I send params : [...].  My RPC json looks identical to the one that is sent when I successfully invoke from within the meteor client.